# Get objectId from key and string value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the Object ID to store in the DB for an array of object.
Any ideas?

```
 //Input
  var data = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'a'
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: 'b'
      }
  ];
```

This is the Object which I'm trying to get the value of, now what I'm trying to achieve is from name I'm trying to get the id value.

**Expected Output**

if the result is 'a' then I should get the value '1',

if the result is 'b' then I should get the value '2'

Anyone has any ideas to work on this.. Kindly help me guys

Answer (score 3):

I would turn the array into an object, so that you can access `obj[name]` to get the `id`:

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, name: 'a'},
  {id: 2, name: 'b'},
  {id: 3, name: 'ccc'}
];
const obj = data.reduce((a, { id, name }) => {
  a[name] = id;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);

// if the name is in a variable:

const name = 'ccc';
console.log(obj[name]);
```

Comment: nice hack! love functional programming

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.find()` :

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'b'
  }
];

function getId(data, name) {
  return typeof name === 'string' ?
    data.find(e => name === e.name).id :
    data.filter(e => name.includes(e.name)).map(e => e.id)
}

var result1 = getId(arr, ['a', 'b']);
var result2 = getId(arr, 'a');

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot guys!**, worked like a charm

Comment: and I have a one more question what if the string value in array like let say

`var arr = ['a', 'b'];`
`data.find(e => e.name === arr);`

can the result be : [1, 2]

Comment: i edited the answer accordingly, if you pass an array, you'll need `includes()` to find the matching eleemnt along with `filter()`

Comment: Yes, working perfect. ** You guys thanks for helping me out!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var data = [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'a'
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: 'b'
      }
  ];

var valuse = data.find(function (el) {
  return el.name == 'b' ;
});


console.log(valuse.id);
```